# can't import facebook api to python code

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

i want to use graph api on python so i can do analysis on posts.
so far i tried to import the library:

```
import facebook
```

but i got the error

```
import facebook
  File "C:\Users\matan\Desktop\Machine Learning Forex\facebook.py", line 11
    pip install -e git+https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk.git#egg=facebook-sdk
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "C:\Users\matan\Desktop\Machine Learning Forex\facebook.py", line 11
    pip install -e git+https://github.com/mobolic/facebook-sdk.git#egg=facebook-sdk
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how can i import this library?

Comment: `pip` is not supposed to be run by the Python interpreter. Where did you find your facebook module? Aren't you missing a step in its installation?

Comment: the only command was the import facebook command

http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting this error because you didn't install the package.
Run this command to [install](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-a-released-version) the package - `pip install facebook-sdk`

Or if you are using python 3 better to run - `pip3 install facebook-sdk`

After installing import the package - `import facebook`

**N.B: It's better to install released versions.**